# How to adjust the language and time settings through the android management API

Tags: android, android-management-api

So we starting with testing the management api on several devices within the company I work for.
Now we got some feedback from our employees who would like to have the 24 hour notation and switch the language to Dutch.
Until now i did not find a way of changing the language settings of the devices through a device policy

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no configuration available in the policy set that will enable you to do those things mentioned, you can only do it during enrollment using the DPC extra you included, or manually.

If you are using QR code or ZT to provision devices, you can add a DPC extra [EXTRA_PROVISIONING_LOCALE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager#EXTRA_PROVISIONING_LOCALE) like the sample code below.

```
qrdata = {
'android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_COMPONENT_NAME': 'com.afwsamples.testdpc/.DeviceAdminReceiver',
'android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_SIGNATURE_CHECKSUM': 'gJD2YwtOiWJHkSMkkIfLRlj-quNqG1fb6v100QmzM9w',
'android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_PACKAGE_DOWNLOAD_LOCATION': 'https://play.google.com/managed/downloadManagingApp?identifier=testdpc',
'android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_USE_MOBILE_DATA':'true',
'android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_LEAVE_ALL_SYSTEM_APPS_ENABLED':'true',
"android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_LOCALE":"nl"
}
```